# Refresh displayed Camera Roll contents

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I use the `UIImagePickerController` class to display the Camera Roll contents. I have a second thread that saves an image to the Camera Roll. When the image has finished saving, it does not appear in the Camera Roll that’s open. Is there a way to force the Camera Roll to refresh? (Other than dismissing and displaying it again.)

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the view for redrawing.

[view setNeedsDisplay];